# Django send_mail doesn't send email, no error given

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, smtp

I am working with Django 2.0.7, using send_mail as described in the docs. Using the below view I receive no mail, but there's also no error.

The settings for sending mail have proven to work, since I do receive the e-mails that are send by the django-rest-auth authentication library.

Considering that I see no error in the send_mail code in my view, I wonder if anyone can help me find out where this goes wrong.

**The view sending the mail:**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def contact(request):
    print("contact view")
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("form is valid")
        print(f"form.cleaned_data:\n{form.cleaned_data}")
        message = create_message(form.cleaned_data)
        send_mail(
            "Test email",
            message,
            'from@example.com',
            ['my@email.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        data = {}
        status = rest_status.HTTP_200_OK
    else:
        print("form NOT valid")
        print(f"form.errors:\n{form.errors}")
        data = form.errors
        status = rest_status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    return Response(data, status=status)
```

Due to the prints I know that the correct view is called, that the POST data is received properly, and that the received data is valid.

I have used a different email address as the recipient in this code than I do in reality, since I don't want spam. But I am sure that I am using the correct recipient email address.

I've also tested if replacing the following line:

```
message = create_message(form.cleaned_data)
```

With the line below changes anything, but it doesn't.

```
message = "Test message"
```

**Email settings:**
(removed actual host address here)

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'xxxx'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['EMAIL_USER']
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly using `send_mail` from python shell? That might give you better insights. Although I cannot find anything wrong with this setup. 
Try checking your mail server as well.

Comment: Thanks. Doing it in the shell gives the same result. No error, no mail received. I'll have to find out how to access the logs of the mail server I guess. It's from a domain host, and it's a new area for me, so I guess I'll have to do a bit of studying.

Comment: Did you find anything because I'm having the same issue.

Comment: It's some time ago. Don't remember how I got around it. So I'm sorry to say that I haven't.